# Can I redirect appname.herokuapp.com to www.app.com?

Tags: heroku

I Heroku, is there any way to get my heroapp domain to point to my custom domain? I have `APPNAME.herokuapp.com` which was setup by heroku and I got `www.appname.com`. `www.appname.com` works. But I want `APPNAME.herokuapp.com` to redirect to `www.appname.com`.

In short:
`appname.herokuapp.com` redirect -> `www.appname.com`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can detect the `Host` header in your code and redirect based on that.
In ruby for example:

```
if ENV["HTTP_HOST"] == "myapp.herokuapp.com"
  // Send the redirection and finish the request
end
```